# Software vs. Applications

Tags: discussion, tags

We have two tags that barely express the same thing :

- `Software`
- `Applications`

I try to merge most of `Applications` into `Software`, but for the last two, I ran into some troubles.

These last two posts concern [iOS applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) and I can't really retag them to `software`.

1. Do we keep the `applications` tag for iOS applications ?
2. Do we merge `applications` into `software` ?
3. Do we create a special tag for iOS applications ?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I see Applications as a subset of Software, but that distinction is probably lost on most people.

While I am all for consistency, I wonder how useful these tags are. Most questions are going to be about either software or hardware. I think software-recommendation is a more meaningful tag.

Comment: That's why I removed `software` where `software-recommendation` was already in place.

Comment: agreed Studer, I did the same thing when I first added all the software-recommendation tags.